# How do I draw the support and resistance lines on a candlestick graph using mplfinance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I need to draw two horizontal lines to show support and resistance.

Here is my code:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import mplfinance as mpf
ts = TimeSeries(key='', output_format='pandas', indexing_type='date')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='MSFT', outputsize='compact')
data = data.sort_values(by=['date'])
data.rename(columns={'date':'Date','1. open':'Open','2. high':'High','3. low':'Low','4. close':'Close','5. volume':'Volume'}, inplace=True)
mpf.plot(data, title='MSFT', ylabel='Price', ylabel_lower='Volume', type='candle', style='charles', volume=True, mav=(50, 200), savefig='test-mplfiance.png')
```

How can I do that?, I managed to draw the candlesticks on the graph but I can't draw the lines.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this thing works. Try to find the support and resistance and add it to `hlines`

```
mpf.plot(data,hlines=dict(hlines=[support,resistance],colors=['g','r'],linestyle='-.'), title='MSFT', ylabel='Price', ylabel_lower='Volume', type='candle', style='charles', volume=True, mav=(50, 200), savefig='test-mplfiance.png')
```